# Add new value to an existing object with a variable content as the key?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object 'unit', whose keys are different teams. Teams' keys are employees. Each employee is an object with its own fields. I'm looping through some files, getting each employee object. Once I get an employee object, I want to place into its proper team within the unit object. For example:

```
var indiv = {'Rich':{'a':3,'b':4,'c':5}};
var teamname = "TeamA";
var unit = {};
unit[teamname] = indiv;

//[object Object] {
//   TeamA: [object Object] {
//     Rich: [object Object] { ... }
//   }
// }
```

Now, how can I add the following element to this object?

```
var indiv2 = {'Tom':{'a':6,'b':8,'c':10}};
```

So that the result is:

```
// [object Object] {
//   TeamA: [object Object] {
//     Rich: [object Object] { ... },
//     Tom: [object Object] { ... }
//   }
// }
```

Any clues? Is the only option turning TeamA into an array of objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is as below. With `unit[teamname] = {};` you save an empty object under the key `teamname`. Then you add the single elements to this object under the keys `Rich` and `Tom`

```js
var rich = {'a':3,'b':4,'c':5}
var tom = {'a':6,'b':8,'c':10}
var name1 = "Rich"
var name2 = "Tom"
var unit = {};
var teamname = "TeamA";
unit[teamname] = {};
unit[teamname][name1] = rich;
unit[teamname][name2] = tom;
console.log(unit);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with Rich and Tom being variables? As in var name1 = "Rich"; var name2 ="Tom" (for the line unit[teamname].Rich)

Comment: Yes, just use bracket notation ( `unit[teamname][name1]`) instead of dot notation `unit[teamname].Rich`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have

```
const indiv = {'Rich':{'a':3,'b':4,'c':5}}
const indiv2 = {'Tom':{'a':6,'b':8,'c':10}}
```

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const indiv = {'Rich':{'a':3,'b':4,'c':5}}
const indiv2 = {'Tom':{'a':6,'b':8,'c':10}}
const unit = { teamA: {} }
Object.assign(unit.teamA, indiv)
console.log(unit.teamA)
Object.assign(unit.teamA, indiv2)
console.log(unit.teamA)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want/can't change  `indiv`, `indiv2` structure, you can do it this way.

Get the key from indiv2 :

```
let key = Object.keys(indiv2)[0]
```

Get values:

```
let values = Object.values(indiv2)[0]
```

And now you can do it like this:

```
unit[teamname][key] = values
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const both = {'Rich':{'a':3,'b':4,'c':5},'Tom':{'a':6,'b':8,'c':10}};
const teamName = "TeamA";
let unit = { [teamName] : {} };
unit[teamName] = {...both}
console.log(unit);
```

One at a time:

```js
const persons = [
  { 'Rich':{'a':3,'b':4,'c':5} },
  { 'Tom':{'a':6,'b':8,'c':10} }
];

const teamName = "TeamA"
let unit = { [teamName]: {} };

persons.forEach(person => unit[teamName] = { ...unit[teamName], ...person })
console.log(unit);
```

Comment: That gives the same result as my last code example. My question asked how can I write first an employee to the TeamA object and then add another employee